# Freeze NFT Account via Delegate Access

Tags: metaplex, metaplex-js, freeze-token-account

I'm trying to freeze an NFT via `createFreezeDelegatedAccountInstruction` but I'm always getting this error: `"failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x3e"`.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
import fs from 'fs'
import { PublicKey, Transaction, Keypair, clusterApiUrl, Connection } from "@solana/web3.js"
import { createApproveInstruction, } from "@solana/spl-token"
import { createFreezeDelegatedAccountInstruction, PROGRAM_ID } from '@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata'

const walletSecretKey = Uint8Array.from(
  JSON.parse(
    fs.readFileSync('./key.json', 'utf8')
  )
)

const USER_WALLET_ADDRESS = 'RANDOM_WALLET_ADDRESS'
const NFT_MINT_ID = new PublicKey('RANDOM_NFT_ID')


const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("mainnet-beta"), "confirmed")
const userWalletAddress = new PublicKey(USER_WALLET_ADDRESS)
const authorityWallet = Keypair.fromSecretKey(walletSecretKey)

// Get block hash
const blockhashObj = await connection.getLatestBlockhash()
const blockhash = blockhashObj.blockhash

// create transaction
const transaction = new Transaction()
transaction.feePayer = userWalletAddress
transaction.recentBlockhash = blockhash

const accountAddress = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(NFT_MINT_ID, userWalletAddress)

transaction.add(
  createApproveInstruction(
    accountAddress,
    authorityWallet.publicKey,
    userWalletAddress,
    1
  )
)

const [edition] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
  [
    Buffer.from("metadata"),
    PROGRAM_ID.toBuffer(),
    NFT_MINT_ID.toBuffer(),
    Buffer.from("edition"),
  ],
  PROGRAM_ID
);

transaction.add(
  createFreezeDelegatedAccountInstruction(
    {
      delegate: authorityWallet.publicKey,
      tokenAccount: accountAddress,
      edition,
      mint: NFT_MINT_ID,
      tokenProgram: PROGRAM_ID,
    },
    PROGRAM_ID
  )
)

// sign transaction
transaction.sign(authorityWallet)

// serialize and return
const serializedTransaction = transaction.serialize({
  requireAllSignatures: false,
});
const transactionBase64 = serializedTransaction.toString("base64");
console.log(transactionBase64)
```

And here's the Front-End's code:

```
const recoveredTransaction = Transaction.from(
  Buffer.from(transactionBase64, "base64")
)
const newTxId = await sendTransaction(recoveredTransaction)
```

I also tried doing each transaction alone ( approve, then freeze ) however, the approve worked and the freeze didn't ( also returned the error above ).

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or there's something wrong in the mechanism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In This Section of the Code the tokenProgram is being passed wrong.

```
createFreezeDelegatedAccountInstruction(
{
  delegate: authorityWallet.publicKey,
  tokenAccount: accountAddress,
  edition,
  mint: NFT_MINT_ID,
  // Import TOKEN_PROGRAM_ADDRESS from @solana/spl-token and add it here
  tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ADDRESS,
},
PROGRAM_ID
)
```